# How to symbolicate crash log with Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, symbolicatecrash

I should have the symbolicate from my device. I followed the instruction from http://jmillerdev.net/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios.

I created the `alias` for Xcode 8

> alias
>   symbolicate="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash
>   -v"

I updated the developer directory

> export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

and then the symbolicate

> symbolicate -o "symbolicatedCrash.txt" "MyAppName 2-12-14, 9-44 PM.crash" "MyAppName.app"

but I have an error

> Symbolicating myInventories170313.crash ... while reading
>   myInventories170313.crash, No such file or directory :  at
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash
>   line 899.

[image: Terminal]

Comment: Try giving it the full path to "myInventories170313.crash".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try using these steps:

1) create a new folder ,lets say "Universe" , to hold the stuff.

2) use the Go to Folder utility from Finder . Use the path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/

Find "symbolicatecrash" file and you can manually copy and paste this file to your Universe folder

3) Place your crash and Archive of your app in your folder ( Archive will hold all the dysm files. Alternatively you can place all your dYsm files )

4) CD to your "Universe" folder directory . Now run this command

**export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"**

5)run the symbolicate command on your crash

**./symbolicatecrash  myCrash.crash > SymbolicatedM.crash**

Voila!! you have your symbolicated crash log.

PS : The added advantage of this is that the above setup is a one time setup and is reusable  .All that is required is just replace your crash file and dysm file , then just repeat step 5 each time you want a new crash symbolicated. Bye bye complicated commands!

Comment: It should be noted that you need to pass in a dsym that's generated from the same commit that the crash log came from. You can do this with the flag `--dsym=/path/to/dsym`

Answer (score 10):

- Try connecting a device.
- Then select Xcode->Devices->View logs.
- Drag the crash log into the left pane, you can re-symbolicate right clicking on the crash log.

Comment: did you tried? I'm sure its working, could you please recheck

Comment: Yes, you forgot to mention to add the dysym logs to Xcode. However i could only achieve partial symbolize.

Comment: I just connected device and took device logs , from the window resymbolicated. NO other files required, no other steps also

Comment: Ok i should mention that I'm not the developer of the project and I don't have the code. I got the logs from apple console.

Comment: In my case, I have to change the file extension to `.crash` because the file sent from App Review had `.txt` as an extension

Comment: This only partially symbolicates it. For me, it only worked on 1 thread.

Comment: "re-symbolicate right clicking" made all the difference for me !!

Answer (score 5):

We had the same issue here and we got this solved with a mix of Vkharb and Enrico responses.

- In the same folder, we included our dsym file (symbols) and crash report correctly renamed to whatever.crash
- Then, open terminal and type the next commands:

> 1. alias symbolicate="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v"
> 2. export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
> 3. symbolicate whatever.crash > SymbolicatedM.crash

And you should see the progress with a final report completed.

Comment: Thanks but symbolicated.crash is not actually symbolicated it looks same as unsymbolicated one.Any ideas ?

Comment: It's really late, but: for some reason I had to use "download debug symbols" button from xcode's organizer for corresponding build. Before that only standard library was symbolicated, after that - my own app was too. @RajanM hope it helps