# Symbolicating crash report

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I have all dSYM files, crash file and .app file in the same folder, using this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783001/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-with-xcode-8) it symbolicates the crash report:

```
symbolicatecrash myCrash.crash > SymbolicatedM.crash
```

But the first few lines still show hex address:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000da338
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   myApp                           0x00000001000da338 0x1000c8000 + 74552
1   myApp                           0x00000001000eac90 0x1000c8000 + 142480
2   myApp                           0x0000000100120340 0x1000c8000 + 361280
3   myApp                           0x0000000100120870 0x1000c8000 + 362608
4   UIKit                           0x000000019467f0ec -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
5   UIKit                           0x00000001947ef6b4 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 168
6   UIKit                           0x000000019467f0ec -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000019467f06c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
8   UIKit                           0x00000001946695e0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440
9   UIKit                           0x0000000194669748 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 800
10  UIKit                           0x000000019467e950 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 576
11  UIKit                           0x000000019467e46c -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2480
12  UIKit                           0x0000000194679804 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3192
13  UIKit                           0x000000019464a418 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
14  UIKit                           0x0000000194e43f64 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2400
15  UIKit                           0x0000000194e3e6c0 __handleEventQueue + 4268
16  UIKit                           0x0000000194e3eaec __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 148
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e4c9424 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e4c8d94 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e4c69a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e3f6d94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
21  GraphicsServices                0x000000018fe60074 GSEventRunModal + 100
22  UIKit                           0x00000001946af130 UIApplicationMain + 208
23  myApp                           0x00000001000d986c 0x1000c8000 + 71788
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018d40559c start + 4
```

Content of the folder is as follow:

> myApp.app.dYSM, myCrash.crash, myApp, myApp.ipa and other dYSM files

How can find the reason of the crash with this log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to download the dSYM.zip from iTunesConnect website and extract it along side these files.